# Test is not getting failed incase any action method fails to execute - selenium & TestNG

Tags: selenium, testng

In my framework - , Test & PageObjModel classes are there. incase any method is not executed because of wrong xpath or other any issue the Test is terminating but in the Report-Console it is showing all the Testcase are PASS.
Any issue in the Action methods of PageObjModel, some times it will skip that particular line of code and continue execution. sometimes entire test is terminating. in both the case Report-Console it is showing all the Testcase are PASS i.e No failures of Testcases.
Please have a look into below example of code and suggest me to fail the TC incase of failures.
I tried to include Assert.fail(), Assert.true(fail) in the "catch" block, though it is showing PASS results.

PageObjModel:

```
class A{
// list of xpaths
public static fibal String Login_xpath = "//*[@id='login'];

public void login(){
try{
// All Action methods are define here

}catch (Exception e){
e.printStackTrace();
//Assert.assertTrue(false);
Assert.fail();
} } }
```

Test class:

```
@Test
public void loginTest(){
//calling methods
xx.login();
}
```

This is just sample code. please help me where can I put Assertions to fail the TC when failure occurs in the code

Comment: I've just tested your structure and it seems working fine.

Comment: Nothing seems to be wrong.

Answer (score 0):

If we are using **try-catch** in your code, please **add throw** as well. otherwise, it won't inform testng about the failure.

```
catch (AssertionError e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        takeSnapShot(action);
        throw e;
    }
```